# Change Text Align On Click

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, text-alignment

I am looking to have a button that shifts the text alignment to the left side whenever it is clicked. This is the function I currently have that doesn't seem to be working:

```
function myFunctionLeft() {
document.getElementById("myAnchor").style.left = "-15px";
document.getElementById("myAnchor").style.align = left;
```

Is there a different way I should be trying to move the text align to the left?

Comment: Try `style.textAlign = "left"`

Comment: Is it need to be pure javascript solution? Or jQuery allowed?

Comment: In relation to what exactly? Can you provide a full page example (full CSS and full HTML)? I guarantee that if you do, you will get your answer much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

`left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom`, only works if the element is `position: absolute || relative`. Just make `#myAnchor` `position: relative`.

See here for [more info on positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Answer (score 0):

`align` is not a valid CSS property. Instead of `.style.align = left;`, you should be using `.style.textAlign = "left";`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about something of this proportion, and the best (In my honest opinion) is to make a CSS class to manipulate values. I would go about doing this in using the class `.align-left`. The CSS would go something like the below:

```
.align-left {
    text-align: left;
    left: -15px;
}
```

And you could toggle the class via the following Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myAnchor").classList.toggle("align-left");
```

This should do what you were attempting to achieve with the above code. I don't know if `myAnchor` is what you are aligning or if it is the button or what, but you should be able to use my code for whatever.

Anyways, I hope it helps, try it out and see how it goes. Try the developer tools equipped in your browser to see if there is issue in your inclusion and good luck!